# AJAX call is not sending data to controller method

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

This is what I have in my JavaScript file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#add-be-submit').click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/snapdragon/blog/new',
        data: JSON.stringify({
            EntryName: $('#add-be-title').val(),
            EntryBody: CKEDITOR.instances.addBeBody.getData()
        }),
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        dataType: 'json'
    }).success(function (data, status) {
        $('#add-be-title').val('');
        CKEDITOR.instances.addBeBody.getData('');
    });
});
```

This is what I have in my Controller:

```
/* ---------- ADD BLOG ENTRTY ---------- */
@RequestMapping(value = "/new", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
public void addBlogEntry(@Valid @RequestBody BlogEntry entry) {
    dao.addBlogEntry(entry);
}
```

The controller itself has a RequestMapping set to "/blog". I can't find the problem. I've set a breakpoint on "dao.addBlogEntry(entry)" and found that the object being passed in has EntryName and EntryBody with null values. But when I check the values of "$('#add-be-title').val()" and "CKEDITOR.instances.addBeBody.getData()" in the JavaScript console they have the correct values.

Any ideas?

Comment: What does http://yourserver.com/snapdragon/blog/new return in the browsers if you allow GET

Comment: May be check request message in browser's developmentTools. I mean Network/Net tab in devTools. you can find your request message, headers and so on.

Comment: I get a 400 Bad Request Error when I allow GET, and a 500 Internal Server Error the way it is described above. The 500 error reads, **"HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException:**

Comment: You need to map RequestMethod.GET to test the URL from the browser

Comment: @mplungjan How do I do this? Change the RequestMethod in the controller to GET, and the ajax call to GET?

Comment: @WagnerColodette  , Case sensitivity also matters a lot. Can you please check the case sensitivity of EntryName and  EntryBody variables in your BlogEntry  class, my assumption is that variables declared will be in  the camel case entryBody and entryName and the corresponding setters would be something like getEntryBody(),setEntryBody() etc. If its true, could be please try modifying your data attribute in your ajax call with the same case that is entryBody and entryName

Comment: @Addy The case sensitivity is correct. In the BlogEntry class it is EntryName and EntryBody.

Comment: @WagnerColodette Could you once  please change it to camel case (entryname and entryBody in both ajax and in the class) and try ? because  when the ajax binds the data to backend object, it will search for setter method with setEntryName() which in your case will be setentryName()?

Comment: @Addy It's working now. Thank you so much! Could you please explain why this solved the problem?

Comment: @WagnerColodette , the ajax binds the data to the backedn object in the same way as code does , i mean it will try to call setEntryBody() in the background,since the case is having issue , values were not able to set , so you are getting null, hope this was helpful ( posting my answer in answer column)

Answer (score 0):

Case sensitivity also matters a lot in Ajax.

Can you please check the case sensitivity of **EntryName** and **EntryBody** variables in your BlogEntry class .

Variables declared should be in camel case like 'entryBody' and 'entryName' and the corresponding setters would be something like getEntryBody(),setEntryBody() etc.

Hence, please modify your data attribute in your ajax call as well as variables in your Class with the same case (Camel Case) that is '**entryBody**' and '**entryName**'